# How can I let a user upload multiple text files and then loop through them and echo the contents of each one in PHP?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a simple HTML form that allows a user to select multiple text files. I want to loop through them and echo each one. I have the following code:

```
Upload text document: <br/><br>
<form action="output.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="documents[]" size="50" multiple="multiple" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Then in output.php when I want to echo through each file and echo its contents. I tried this code:

```
$filenames = array();

if(isset($_FILES["documents"]))
{
   for($i=0; $_FILES['documents']['name'][$i] != '' ; $i++)
   {
       $filenames[$i] = $_FILES['documents']['name'][$i];

       $myfile = fopen("$_FILES['documents']['name'][$i]", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

       echo fread($myfile,filesize("$_FILES['documents']['name'][$i]"));

       fclose($myfile);

    }

}
```

I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\ValenceV1\ValenceV1_output.php

How can I fix this code, or if there is a better way to do this please do provide it. Thanks.

Comment: ditch the wrapping double quotes `"$_FILES['documents']['name'][$i]"` it doesn't make sense having that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code, that error was triggered on those lines which has been wrapped with double quotes and then wrapping array indices with the single one. If you expect to read those files without using `move_upload_file()`, use the `tmp_name` index instead to read the temp file:

```
<?php

$contents = '';
if(isset($_FILES['documents'])) {
    $num_of_files = count($_FILES['documents']['name']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_of_files; $i++) {
        $tmp = $_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $contents .= file_get_contents($tmp);
    }
    echo $contents;
}

?>
```

If you decided the `foreach` flavor directly pointing to `tmp_name`:

```
$contents = '';
if(isset($_FILES['documents'])) {
    foreach($_FILES['documents']['tmp_name'] as $tmp) {
        $contents .= file_get_contents($tmp);
    }
    echo $contents;
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks for that. this is more straightforward. @Ghost

Comment: @modarwish sure no prob glad this helped

Comment: Why use `count()`, and not just a `foreach` loop?

Comment: @PHPglue im just feeding off from what the OP has used, could use `foreach`, no harm in using this anyways

Answer (score 1):

Why you enclosed the vars by double quotes? Remove the quotes & can try what I posted.

```
$filenames = array();
if(isset($_FILES["documents"]))
{
    for($i=0; $_FILES['documents']['name'][$i] != '' ; $i++)
    {
        $filenames[$i] = $_FILES['documents']['name'][$i];
        $myfile = fopen($_FILES['documents']['name'][$i], "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
                       /*^^^*/                       /*^^^*/ 
        echo fread($myfile,filesize($_FILES['documents']['name'][$i]));
        fclose($myfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting warning: fopen(file1.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\ValenceV1\output.php. I selected two text files, clicked upload, and then the error I got. Any idea why? @void main